# Custom iterator to a single object

Tags: java, iterator

I'm trying to create an iterator to a single object (file for example). It must return a single file. But when I test this code, instead of a single path it returns an infinite loop of paths!

```
public class File {
public String path;
public File(String str){
   path = str;
}

    @Override
    public Iterator<File> iterator() {
        // TODO
        RegularFile r = this;
        return new Iterator<File>() {
            private boolean i;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext(){
                return !i;
            }
            @Override
            public File next() {
                if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
                    i = true;
                    return r;
                            }

        };
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
        File f = new File("C:\temp");
        while (f.iterator().hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(f.iterator().next().path);
        }
}
```

What is wrong?!

Answer (score 3):

This method creates an `Iterator` every time you call it.

```
public Iterator<File> iterator() {
    // TODO
    RegularFile r = this;
    return new Iterator<File>() {
```

You call that method every time you go around the loop, creating a fresh `Iterator` each time.

```
    while (f.iterator().hasNext()) {
```

(I have to say, the variable name `i` and the logical negations don't help reading this code. This indentation in `next()` is all over the place - the statements on the the line after the `if` look as if they are part of a "then" block, but aren't. `Collections.singleton​(path).iterator()` would work.)